# Standard Deviation: Probablity analysis

Tags: mean-variance

Stock E has an average return of 13.6% and a standard deviation of 9%, what is the probability that Stock E will return less than -4.4%

Comment: I saw a similar post earlier, but now mine said it is off-topic? Not too sure about this?

Comment: Can you derive your result from the similar post you saw?

Comment: You will get better answers on https://math.stackexchange.com if you change "average return" to "mean" and indicate that it assumes a normal distribution.